# Change the name of different groups with same prefix in a long data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame in long format that I want to merge different groups with the same prefix. The structure of the df I am working with is as follows:

```
 id point variable value
 1531 36   P6A     area   290
 1532 48   P6B     area   230
 1533 60   P5A     area   20
 1534 72   P5B     area   180
 1535 84   P4A     area   100
 1536 96   P4B     area   90
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
 id point variable value
 1531 36   P6     area   260
 1533 60   P5     area   100
 1535 84   P4     area   80
```

Note that the new value is the mean of PxA and PxB.

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me out.

Murillo

Comment: It looks like the mean for `P4` should be 95.

Comment: yeah, I did it by hand and made a mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to keep the first two characters from each value (as in your example data) then you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

dfMean = df %>% mutate(point = substr(point, 1,2)) %>%
       group_by(point) %>%
       summarise(PointMean = mean(value))
```

A base R option would be to use `aggregate`:

```
df$point2 = substr(df$point, 1,2)
aggregate(value ~ point2, data=df, mean)
```